# Please help me with this C# code

Tags: c#-4.0

Why is the output of the given 200 and not 20000 as I had expected ????

Please help me on this !!!

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        mukul x = new mukul();
        x.b= 200;
        Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(x.calculate));
        Console.ReadLine()
     }
}

class mukul
{    
     public  int b;

     public int calculate 
     {
         get { return  b; }
         set { b = value * 100; }
     } 
}
```

Comment: Setting x.b assigns a value to the field. Calling x.calculate calls the "get" on the property. The "set" is never called. Use x.calculate=200.

Answer (score 9):

You're setting `x.b` directly - you're not using the `calculate` setter, so it's not multiplying by 100.

If you changed this line:

```
x.b = 200;
```

to this:

```
x.calculate = 200;
```

then it would act as you expect.

There are several points to make though:

- If you indent your code properly, it will make it easier to read
- If your `b` field were private, you couldn't have set it directly. Fields should almost *always* be private.
- You should follow normal .NET naming conventions (PascalCase for properties and types, for example)
- Your property is very odd. It's very unusual for code like this:

  ```
  x.calculate = x.calculate;
  ```

  to actually make a difference. I would rethink your design if I were you.
- If you're calling `Console.WriteLine`, there's already an overload to handle an `int` value, and even if there weren't the value could be boxed to `object` instead. So your code would be written more simply as:

  ```
  Console.WriteLine(x.calculate);
  ```

Answer (score 0):

In this " x.b= 200;" you calling only "b" variable.not "calculate" method.So every time you get the 200 as  output with out performing calculate method.

For better understanding

Take two breakpoints at the below two instructions

get { return b; }

set { b = value * 100; }

Then perform stepinto debug(press F11) for the two instructons like "x.b=200" and "x.claculate=200".Then observe the difference between "x.b=200" and "x.claculate=200"

### In x.b=200

"set{b=value*100;}"method cant execute.That means b=value*100 not executed.So every time you get "200" as output.

### In x.calculate=200

"set{b=value*100;}"method is executed.That means b assigned with value*100.So you get "20000" as output.

Finally you have to call method("calculate") not variable("b").

Hope you got the answer.Have a happy Programming........